# Measuring kernel memory usage of a FUSE-based application

Tags: memory, linux-kernel, fuse

I'm designing a FUSE-based file-system for an embedded system, thus under strict memory constraints. The path of data is long between an application calling fwrite and the actual FUSE-based application, and several copies of data are performed in the Kernel.

I would like to measure the amount of memory that is reserved in the Kernel space for FUSE to transfert the data, either through some tools that could allow me to do that (on Linux 2.6), or thanks to any good documentation.

Thanks